# Magic Mouse 2 no longer connecting to my M1 Mac Mini

Tags: bluetooth, mouse

Just started this morning. When I plug up the mouse to the Mac Mini (via a lightening to USB cable) I can see the mouse and macOS *says* "Your mouse is wirelessly connected to this Mac." But apparently it's lying to me...

When I unplug it I cannot use the mouse (wireless connection over bluetooth does not work).

I have tried:

- Turning bluetooth off and on
- Turning the mouse off and on
- Unpairing and re-pairing the mouse
- Rebooting the Mac
- Updating macOS Ventura to latest / installing all updates

Nothing is working. Please help, this is main machine and I really need it.

[image: Bluetooth settings show mouse when connected via USB]

Comment: The battery is probably no longer a holding a charge. When you have it plugged in, it's being charged and powered.  After you plug it in and macOS says it's connected, disconnect the mouse and see how fast you lose the connection.

Comment: Thanks, Allan. Yes, I think you're right. I called Apple support and they also said it sounds like the mouse is just dead. :(

Comment: I just tried it on my MBP and the behavior is exactly the same

Comment: The battery is something you could [reasonably change](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Magic+Mouse+2+Battery+Replacement/146363) if so inclined.  It's definitely easier to get a new mouse, but I'm all for keeping eWaste to a minimum as much as possible.

Comment: If you write up your answer, ping me here and I'll send an upvote your way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal battery in the Magic Mouse 2 has permanently died. I am a big proponent of DIY and reducing e-waste (used to replace the battery in my old iPods years ago) so am going to try and replace the battery via:

- https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Magic+Mouse+2+Battery+Replacement/146363

Comment: Found the battery for sale here on AliExpress: https://www.aliexpress.com/i/3256802762280000.html?gatewayAdapt=4itemAdapt

Comment: Awesome!  I am right there with you on reducing eWaste!

Comment: Thank you, Allan! :)